# jQuery.post() with URL set as a Java weblet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, xss, tomcat6

I have a java app on my server and I can access it with my browser by going to `server.com:8080/app`.

I've been trying to get my application to access this weblet but because of XSS `jQuery.post()` gives me errors. Both the app and weblet are on the same server, but since I have to access the weblet through port 8080 Javascript thinks it's another server.

My question: Is there a way to avoid this XSS issue?

I don't want to use a PHP proxy or .htaccess. I also don't want to use the `$.getJSON(url + '&callback?')` method.

I'm looking for any other solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What reason do you have to not use those methods?

Comment: Using a PHP proxy will slow down performance. .htaccess is just annoying because I have a lot of variables I need to pass, which change frequently, so I don't want edit it everytime. And I've been messing around with JSONP but I keep getting weird or no data.

Comment: I don't see why you would have XSS issues by using the port 8080. I do that all the time without any problem. The app is served by the same server, on the same port, right?

Comment: I have a browser based, port 80, application that needs to access the data of the java app on port 8080. In order to do that I have to put 'server.com:8080/app' as the URL parameter in $.post(). That gives me: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load myURL. Origin myServer is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: Ah, OK. It wasn't clear to me that you had two applications running on two different ports. Why don't you make everything run on the same port?

Answer (score 0):

It' SOP(Same Origin Policy) that's stopping you here, not XSS. XSS is a security vulnerability, which breaks SOP. And yes it limits access so both pages have to run on the same protocol, port and domain.

Can you use a reverse proxy from the webserver on port 80 to 8080? If not you could take a look at easyXDM. Another alternative is to have the 8080 service return rhe access control header mentioned in one of your comments, but this is not supported in older browsers.